# Change source at runtime for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am planning to implement the jquery-ui-autocomplete for multiple sources. Here's my scenario: I want to have multiple autocomplete sources based on some conditions. Here is my code:

```
var arrLookup = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var arrA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'];
var arrB = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'];
var arrC = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'];
var arrD = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'];

$('#txt').autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
         // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
         response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(arrLookup, request.term.split(/,\s*/).pop()));
   },
   minLength: 1,
   select: function (event, ui) {
      var terms = split(this.value);
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
   }
});
```

Now what I want is that, initially the autocomplete source should be arrLookup. If I select a, the source should get modified to arrA, if I select b; he source modified to arrB, so on and so forth. Now since it will be a multi value autocomplete, once I hit "," the source switched back to arrLookup. Can anyone help me out switching sources. I know it can be possible via source only, but I am not able to get the correct condition.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Couldn't you just place logic inside of your `source` function to look into the correct array?

Comment: I tried, but I am not able to get the logic to do so. First thing is I need to extract all data after the last ",". Then I need to parse data again to switch data source. A bit complicated i think. Although doable, but not able to get the correct condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the jQuery autocomplete plugin (which has a "setOptions" method) instead of the jQuery-ui one.

Check out this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868537/ajax-autocomplete-for-jquery-how-to-send-dynamic-parameters)** for more info.

**UPDATE:** [Here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-pass-more-than-one-param-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete) is another example of how to do it while still using jQuery-ui. Look at the final post made by the guy whole originally started the thread.