# Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery : How To Send Dynamic Parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i am using `Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery` ( http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ ) in one of my application. The Search Form looks something like this :

```
<form id="topsearch" method="POST" action="/searchAll"><input type="text" class="searchform" name="q" id="q" value="Country, City, Hotel or a Tourist Attraction" o    nfocus="clearInput(this);" onblur="defaultInput(this);" />
  <select id="top_search_select" name="entity_type">
     <option value="country">Countries</option>
     <option value="city">Cities</option>
     <option value="place" selected="selected">Tourist Attractions</option>
     <option value="hotel">Hotels</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="topsearch" class="submit" value="SEARCH" title="SEARCH"/>
</form>
```

and the autocomplete configuration looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
   var a = $('#q').autocomplete({
     serviceUrl:'/search',
     delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
     maxHeight:400,
     width:325,
     zIndex: 9999,
     params: {entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()},
     deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
     noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
     onSelect: function(value, data){window.location.replace(data);},
   });
 //]]>
</script>
```

Now the problem is in the backend i have different handlers that generate results for different types of entity that user would choose through the select option in the form.

By Default `entity_type` is `place` which is being passed just fine to the handler in the backend. However, what i want is when a person selects a different entity from the select box in the form `params: {entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()}` in the script configuration also gets updated.

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setOptions method worked, though we need to call it on the selects change method. So change script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  var a = $('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl:'/search',
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    maxHeight:400,
    width:325,
    zIndex: 9999,
    params: {entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()},
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
    onSelect: function(value, data){window.location.replace(data);},
  });
  a.setOptions({params:{entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()}});
//]]>
</script>
```

and On document ready function add this :

```
$("#top_search_select").change(function() {
  a.setOptions({params:{entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()}});
});
```

Comment: I tried using your solution but to no avail.. What has to be done for passing dynamic parameters.

Comment: call "setOptions" method maybe :/

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you can specify the params using a function which is evaluated just before the ajax request is sent.

```
$('#q').autocomplete({
    ...
    params: {
        'entity_type': function() {
            return $('#top_search_select').val();
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest way to handle it.  It's a much better solution than solutions that call setOptions() each time something changes.

Answer (score 2):

Might be an old question, but I feel that here's the best way to do it:

```
$('#q').autocomplete({
    ...
    onSearchStart: function(q) {
        q.entity_type = $('#top_search_select').val();
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use a function for the params option (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

As your plugins site specifies in the usage here http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ it has a `setOptions` method on the object it returns which you can use later to change options dynamically.

Add a `onchange` handler on the select element and change the `params` options each time user selects a different value like

```
$(function(){
  var ac = $('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl:'/search',
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    maxHeight:400,
    width:325,
    zIndex: 9999,
    params: {entity_type:$('#top_search_select').val()},
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
    onSelect: function(value, data){window.location.replace(data);},
  });

  $("#top_search_select").change(function() {
      ac.setOptions({params:{entity_type:$(this).val()}});
  });


});
```

You should put all your code inside `document ready`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, the source method for some reason do not work. I have solved it using the setOptions message though.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are using jQuery UI autocomplete. Updated answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pez's answer didnt work for me just a slight variation with 'extraParams'. This makes the parameters dynamic rather than set on page load...

```
$("#field").autocomplete('pageurl.php', {     
   width: 240,
   matchContains: true,
   mustMatch: false,
   selectFirst: false,
   extraParams: {
      start:function () { 
           return $("#start_date").val(); 
      },
      end: function () {
           return $("#end_date").val() ;
      }
  } 
});
```

Comment: There is no such parameter "extraParams" in DevBridge's AutoComplete.  You're probably using a different AutoComplete script.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above did NOT work for me (I suspect because I'm passing "POST" data through ajaxSettings variable which might affect "params" but I did not double check).

Anyway all comments gave good hints and I came up with the following:

```
var data={          
    'phrase': function() {
        return $('#ajax_post').val();
    },
    'activity_id': function() {
        return $('#activity_id').val();
    }
}

var options = {
    noCache: true,
    transformResult: function(response) {
        //whatever
    },
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        //whatever
    },  
    serviceUrl: "MyPHP.php",
    ajaxSettings: {
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    }
};  

$("#ajax_post").autocomplete(options);
```

So I was able to deliver to the PHP script both the content of ajax_post and activity_id input fields.

Note that it's not enough to do:

```
'phrase': $('#ajax_post').val()
```

Because as mentioned in other answers the value get static.