# how to pass dynamic parameters in jquery.autocomplete.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using [autocomplete](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) for my project of auto selecting cities and areas. I want to now dynamically autoselect areas of city selected. Though the autosearch is working quite well I just not able to send the dynamice cityid for the area. How am I to do this? I tried the option given in [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868537/ajax-autocomplete-for-jquery-how-to-send-dynamic-parameters) but to no avail.My code till date:

*HTML*

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid_search_city_id" name="hid_search_city_id" value="">
```

*SCRIPT*

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#hid_search_city_id").change(function() {
        areas.setOptions({
            params: {
                entity_type: $('#hid_search_city_id').val()
            }
        });
    });
});
var baseUrl = $('input#baseUrl').val();
var url = baseUrl + 'ajax/getSearchCities';
$('input#search_cities').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: url,
    minChars: 1,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 300,
    deferRequestBy: 0,
    onSelect: function(value, data) {
        $('#id').val(+data);
        $('#hid_search_city_id').val('');
        $('#hid_search_city_id').val(data);
    }
})
var url = baseUrl + 'ajax/getSearchAreas';
var areas = $('input#search_areas').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: url,
    minChars: 1,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 300,
    params: {
        entity_type: $('#hid_search_city_id').val()
    },
    deferRequestBy: 0,
    onSearchStart: function(q) {
        areas.entity_type = $('input#search_cities').val();
    },
    onSelect: function(value, data) {
        $('#id').val(+data);
    },
});
areas.setOptions({
    params: {
        entity_type: $('#hid_search_city_id').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: you have to add the value of the city and the cityid in the input fieldsm using $('input#city').val(city); and $('input#cityid').val(cityid);

Comment: @Gaurav don't understand your ans. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why are you binding auto-complete outside document-ready handler?

Comment: @Satpal autocomplete has to be dynamic and not just run once when document ready.

Comment: document ready hadler executes when document is ready. What do you mean by has to be dynamic. Just test `alert($('input#search_areas').length)` and tell us what you get?